# How to deploy angular app to IIS in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Could anybody provide steps to deploy/publish ASP.NET Boilerplate Angular app to IIS?

I have found no documentation on https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents

I'm using Asp.Net Core Single Page Angular template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ng build --prod

It will create a dist folder which could be deployed to IIS. (that is for Angular 6, for earlier versions of angular use parameter -prod)